# Setup Small Home ESXi 4.0 Server

Tags: home-networking, switch, esxi

I was wondering if anyone has could create a How-to for Installing and Setup of a Home Network for the Freeware Version of VMWare ESXi Server 4.0
Here is what I have thus far.

- Server Case
- Motherboard with /Quad Core Intel Chipset
- 8 Gig of memory
- 850 GB Hard Drives /SATA
- Video Card
- 2 Network Cards

What I'm trying to do is:
Setup the VMWare ESXi Server 4.0 (I have installed this already, and it works fine.)
I want to Install 4 Windows Servers 2008 r2
I then want to install SQL Server 2008 r2
I would also like to setup DNS/Active Directory/Users and Computers Setup.
I'm also wanting to install MS SharePoint Server 2010 (I know how to install this also.)

My problem is how to network this in a home environment...  (Above is what I have already installed on my VMWare Server 4.0 Freeware version...)
I want this to be a live environment so while I'm learning C# (C Sharp / MS Sharepoint Designer 2010...  This will all be using 64bit OS and Applications MS Office 2010 64bit etc.)

I want to develop and create SharePoint Templates and Solutions to Deploy using MS Visual studio C# and Microsoft Sharepoint Designer 2010...

All I want is for someone to Create a Network that will let you remote desktop and user your browser for IE 8 or Firbox web browser.
I want to share network of servers and pcs at home...
this is some how done via-vmware switch...   but I'm not sure how to do this...
Any help would be great!

Comment: What does your network currently look like?

Comment: Are you just trying to get all your VMs on the local network? It's unclear what specific question you're asking beyond what [VMWare's documentation](http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/vs_pages/vsp_pubs_esxi40_u1_i_vc40_u1.html) covers in multiple ways.

Answer (score 1):

If your focus is to learn C#, Sharepoint, SQL Server 2008 and Windows Setup, why are you complicate the problem?

Judging from your need, you can just install everything in 1 server and focus on that.

Don't add esxi management + virtual-network to the picture. You would only complicate things.